# Extra Characters when pulling from HealthKit

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, hksamplequery

When I pull my HealthKit data using HKSampleQuery, I create an array and then populate a tableview. However, when I do this my tableViewCell has many other characters after the blood sugar number. Here's a screenshot of the cell:

[image]

Heres where I query the data. Any help please!

```
    let endDate = NSDate()
    let startDate = NSCalendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: number, to: endDate as Date)
    let sampleType = HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodGlucose)
    let mostRecentPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate as Date, options: [])
    let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sampleType!, predicate: mostRecentPredicate, limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit, sortDescriptors: nil) { (query, results, error) in
        if let results = results as? [HKQuantitySample] {
            self.bloodGlucose = results
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    healthStore.execute(query)
```

Here's where I setup the tableview...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return bloodGlucose.count
  }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
                let currentCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
                let sugar = bloodGlucose[indexPath.row]
                currentCell.textLabel?.text = "\(sugar)"
                currentCell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sugar.startDate)
                return currentCell
 }
```

Comment: Please include the code you use for setting up the table view cells.

Comment: I edited the question to include this. @Allan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are showing whole String representation of `HKQuantitySample`. If you want to show only quantity of the `HKQuantitySample`, why don't you use its `quantity` property?

```
currentCell.textLabel?.text = "\(sugar.quantity)"
```

---

By the way, you better declare your `endDate` as `Date` (not `NSDate`):

```
let endDate = Date()
let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: number, to: endDate)
let sampleType = HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bloodGlucose)
let mostRecentPredicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate)
```

Generally, non-`NS` types work better with Swift.

Comment: Worked great! Thank you!

Comment: Note that generating the label text this way is never going to localize properly, the string returned from the `description` method of `HKQuantity` is for debugging purposes only. If what you want to do is display a localized string representation you need to use something like `NSMeasurementFormatter`.